# Problema con una consulta SQL muy basica

Tags: sql, subconsultas

La consulta es la siguiente:

Obtener para cada departamento cuántos empleados trabajan, la suma de sus salarios y la suma de sus comisiones para aquellos departamento en los que hay algún empleado cuyo salario es superior a 1700 euros.

He intentado la siguiente orden, para empezar poco  a poco, pretendo que me diga cuantos empleados hay en cada departamento, pero da error: la funcion de grupo no es de grupo unico

```
select count(*), coddpto from empleado order by coddpto
```

la tabla dpto es:

```
    CODDPTO NUMBER
*    DENOMINACION VARCHAR2
F * CODCENTRO NUMBER 
    CODDPTODEPENDE NUMBER
F * CODEMPLEJEFE NUMBER
  * TIPO        CHAR
  * PRESUPUESTO NUMBER 
FK_CODCENTRO (CODCENTRO)
FK_CODEMPLEJEFE (CODEMPLEJEFE)
```

y la tabla empleado es:

```
    CODEMPLE NUMBER 
  * APE1 VARCHAR2 
  * APE2 VARCHAR2 
  * NOMBRE VARCHAR2 
  * DIRECCION VARCHAR2 
  * LOCALIDAD VARCHAR2 
    TELEF VARCHAR2 
  * CODDPTO NUMBER 
F * CODCATE NUMBER 
  * FECHAINGRESO DATE
  * SALARIO NUMBER 
    COMISION NUMBER 
PK_CODEMPLE (CODEMPLE)
FK_CODCATE (CODCATE)
PK_CODEMPLE (CODEMPLE)
```

[image: la imagen es la tabla empleado]

Comment: ¿Cuál es la duda?, ¿qué has intentado?, checa [ask]

Comment: He intentado varias consultas con select -- from empleado, pero me salta error en sql developer

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon tu codigo ahi

Comment: @RHAAPHAA, hola podrías decirnos si resolviste tu problema, y darle un voto a las respuestas que te sirvieron y marcar como aceptada la que consideres mejor, gracias

Comment: Perdona, si el codigo que escribió Japv ha sido el que finalmente me llevo a la solucion, es la siguiente:                                                              select coddpto, count(*), sum(salario), sum(comision) 
from empleado 
where coddpto in (select distinct(coddpto) from empleado where salario >1700)
group by coddpto 
order by coddpto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select d.NombreDpto, 
       count(e.codEmple) as Empleados, 
       sum(e.salario) as Salario, 
       sum(e.Comision) as Comisiones
from empleado e inner join departamento d on e.coddpto = d.coddpto
where e.salario > 1700
group by d.NombreDpto
```

Se hace un **inner join** para juntar las **tablas empleados** y **departamento** por el campo que las relaciona que en este caso es **coddpto**, posteriormente se filtra mediante un **where** todos los empleados que tienen un salario mayor que **1700**, después se **agrupa** por el nombre del departamento, y de esta forma se va a **seleccionar** para cada departamento el nombre del departamento, la cantidad de trabajadores que trabajan en el, el total del salario de sus trabajadores y el total de sus comisiones.

Answer (score 0):

La consulta segun lo que entiendo puede ser muy sencilla.

Yo en mi caso aplicaría los 3 agrupados en una sola consulta.

- **count(*)** para contar todos los registros de empleados
- **Sum(SALARIO)** me sumaria todo los salarios sin ninguna condición.
- **sum(CASE WHEN e.SALARIO  > 1700 THEN e.COMISION  ELSE 0 END)**, sumar las comisiones, cuando el salario sea mayor a 1700 regresara y sumara la comisión, cuando el salario sea menor, regresara y sumara 0.

```sql
    select e.coddpto, d.DENOMINACION , count(*), sum(e.SALARIO) Salario, sum(CASE WHEN e.SALARIO  > 1700 THEN e.COMISION  ELSE 0 END) Comision,   
    from empleado e
        inner join dpto  d on e.CODDPTO  = d.CODDPTO 
    group by e.coddpto, d.DENOMINACION 
    order by coddpto
```

```
select e.coddpto, d.DENOMINACION , count(*), sum(e.SALARIO) Salario, sum  (e.COMISION),   
    from empleado e
        inner join dpto d on e.CODDPTO  = d.CODDPTO 
    group by e.coddpto, d.DENOMINACION 
    order by coddpto
```

Comment: Creo que la condición del salario es para todos los empleados, no solo para la suma de comisiones. Pero supongo que queda abierto a interpretación.

Comment: Me salta error porque falta paréntesis derecho. He metido varios pero no corrijo el error.  La consulta es decir cuantos empleados hay en cada departamento (tienen igual codigo de departamento), la suma de sus salarios (dentro del mismo departamento) y la suma de sus comisiones

Comment: quite los paréntesis, no se por que los había incluido, perdón

Comment: y si solo ocupas la suma de la comision, entonces quita el case when ,  y deja solo el sum(e.comision)